# AVPlayer not playing audio - iOS 9, Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am trying to play audio from a URL in my app. Everything happens as expected in iOS 8 (simulator and physical devices). For iOS 9, it works in simulator but on device, the audio simply does not play. The streaming appears, if I click on play, the progress bar also shows that audio is getting loaded and playing but the sound does not come. This issue is happening in iOS 9 physical device. It works totally fine with iOS 8 physical device.

I created a simple button. On clicking on button, the AVPlayerViewController is loaded and AVPlayer is initialized with the given  URL. The code is following:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://path/to/my.mp3"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"playSegue" sender:url];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    AVPlayerViewController *viewController = (AVPlayerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    viewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:(NSURL *)sender];
}

@end
```

Comment: is the url nil in your prepare for segue ?

Comment: No. I did `NSLog("%@", (NSURL *)sender)` and it gave the the URL in my log.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After doing various trial and error tactics for over 5 days, I finally figured out that my problem was with the mute switch of the phone. When it is on mute, the audio does't play! So, I added the following line of code to specify my category as playback and now it plays even when my device switch is on mute

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Thank you!

Comment: Saved my ass .Thanks

Comment: This code works for me too, thanks, But I could not find out in iPhone which switch you are talking about. which is mute ?

Comment: @ArpitBParekh The switch I mentioned is on the left side panel on top above the volume rocker button. If the code worked and helped you, upvote would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Ohk, the switch is hardware button of iPhone, I got now. Thanks.

Comment: Not working for me though :((( Video file has sound and the player is not muted. The volume is at max too.  and I added this too but still not working

Comment: new version of swift: audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)

Answer (score 5):

For anyone with this same issue, here is the Swift solution.

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [])
```

And some [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes.html)

Comment: ```try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])``` for Swift 4.2