# AVPlayer is not playing audio from Document directory using Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avplayer, nsdocumentdirectory

I have an audio files, stored in Document directory. I want play it using AVPlayer but it is not playing. I am using Swift3.

```
 var myurl : NSURL!
 var audioPlayer = AVPlayer()

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
 // Getting sound from Document directory

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let docsurl = try! fileManager.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)

    myurl  = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("/\(songName!)")

   playSound(url:  myurl! as NSURL)

  }
   // Playing Sound

  func playSound(url:NSURL){

        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url as URL, options: nil)

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

        self.audioPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)

        let durationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)

        self.getSeconds = Int(durationInSeconds)

         self.audioPlayer.play()
         }
```

I am getting url from document directory, but it is not playing. Don't know why? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is it giving any kind of error in logs? If not try referring to this https://stackoverflow.com/q/33147928/4618125

Comment: No, i printed player item, and result is :- playerItem <AVPlayerItem: 0x608000204a40, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x6080006218e0, URL = file:///Users/valleyworks/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2B9AF8B2-1A4E-4E11-9B80-1E1975B6805E/data/Containers/Data/Application/969DD15D-ED7F-4EEE-BA8A-FB2EE47C3ACE/Documents/First+Excursion.m4a>>

Comment: Try doing as mentioned in above reference link

Comment: Thanks for reply, @Rohan, can you please provide this solution in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in `AppDelegate.swift` file in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method and see if you can hear the audio:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
}catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I already added this code for playing music in background and lock screen.